# From React to Vue, how to loop through an array with .map method?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm using vue and came from a react background. React had this method called .map where if you pass in an array as props then it would render that component multiple times, depending on the number of items in the array and extract each data from the index. Like this:

```js
function App() {
const classes = useStyles();
const [finance, setFinance] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
    axios
        .all([
            axios.get(
                `https://cloud.iexapis.com/stable/stock/market/collection/list?collectionName=gainers&token=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX`
            ),
        ])

        .then((res) => {
            setFinance(res[0].data);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
        });
}, []);

const cardList = finance.map((company, index) => (
    <Grid item xs={10} sm={5} md={4} lg={3} xl={2}>
        <Cards company={company} index={index} />
    </Grid>
));
```

Basically, `finance` is a state where all the data from an array is stored. and I pass that data of `company` as a prop to the `Cards` component.  This works and I'm trying to replicate this effect in vue. Here is my code so far:

```html
<template>
  <v-container>
    <v-row align="start" justify="center">
      <v-col xs="12" sm="6" md="4" lg="3">
        <cards :crypto="crypto[0]" />
      </v-col>
    </v-row>
  </v-container>
</template>

<script>
import cards from "@/components/cards.vue";

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      crypto: []
    };
  },
  components: { cards },
  mounted() {
    this.axios
      .get(
        "https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/top/totalvolfull?limit=20&tsym=USD&api_key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
      )
      .then(response => {
        this.crypto = response.data.Data;
        console.log(response.data.Data);
      })
      .catch(error => console.log(error));
  }
};
</script>
```

As you can see, `crypto` is a data property that I pass in the `cards` component in Vue. What I'd like to do is the exact same thing I did with React, whereas I pass an array of objects into a component, and the component renders multiple times depending on the number of objects of the array while getting the data from the corresponding index. I tried doing the v-for directive but I think that only works on lists? Any help is appreciated.

Note:
Here is the Card component of my Vue project for context:

```html
<template>
  <v-card class="mx-auto" max-width="344" outlined>
    <v-list-item three-line>
      <v-list-item-content>
        <div class="overline mb-4">{{ crypto.CoinInfo.FullName }}</div>
        <v-list-item-title class="headline mb-1">{{
          crypto.CoinInfo.Name
        }}</v-list-item-title>
        <v-list-item-subtitle
          >Price: {{ crypto.DISPLAY.USD.PRICE }}<br />Change :
          {{ crypto.DISPLAY.USD.CHANGEDAY }}</v-list-item-subtitle
        >
      </v-list-item-content>

      <!-- <v-list-item-avatar tile size="80" -->
      <img
        style="height: 80px;"
        :src="`https://www.cryptocompare.com/${crypto.CoinInfo.ImageUrl}`"
      />
      <!-- </v-list-item-avatar> -->
    </v-list-item>

    <v-card-actions>
      <v-btn text>Save</v-btn>
      <v-btn text>Check</v-btn>
    </v-card-actions>
  </v-card>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  props: {
    crypto: Object
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: "*React had this method called .map*" - no. `finance` is a plain array value, and it has the [builtin `map` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map). You can use that in vue.js exactly the same.

Comment: That's partially true, you can only use `.map` in Vue's vdom when using render functions instead of `<template>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the `v-for` directive: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Mapping-an-Array-to-Elements-with-v-for

Trying to match your React example, your case would be something like:

```
<v-col v-for="(cryptoItem, index) in crypto" xs="11" sm="6" md="4" lg="3">
  <cards :crypto="cryptoItem" :index="index" />
</v-col>
```

Comment: I'll see if that works. Most of the samples people gave was just using lists and not really components. Will give it a shot

Comment: it says  "Custom element in iteration require 'v-bind:key'

Comment: Ahh got it. just needed to v-bind key.

Answer (score 0):

Projects generated with Vue CLI can also use [JSX in a `render` function](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html#JSX), which lets you do something similar to the React solution. This isn't necessarily a "better" solution than using `v-for`, but just an alternative option if you prefer JSX.

For example, a container component could fetch data, and assign the result to a prop bound to a `CardList` component, which maps the prop to an array of `Card` components:

*Container.vue*:

```html
<template>
  <CardList :crypto="crypto" />
</template>

<script>
export default {
  async mounted() {
    const { data } = await axios.get(...)
    this.crypto = data
  }
}
</script>
```

*CardList.vue*:

```html
<script>
export default {
  props: {
    crypto: {
      type: Array,
      required: true,
      default: () => [],
    },
  },
  render() {
    return (
      <v-container>
        <v-row align="start" justify="center">
          <v-col xs="12" sm="6" md="4" lg="3">
            { this.crypto.map(crypto => <Card crypto={crypto} />) }
          </v-col>
        </v-row>
      </v-container>
    )
  },
};
</script>
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/render-with-jsx-in-vue-5v9ex?file=/src/components/CardList.vue)

Comment: Oh wow, really? Dammmn. I didn't know that. Great tip, will definitely use this in the future.